# Unable to send.a put request with a header in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

Here's my PUT request:

```
  put :my_action123, 
    params: { 
      var1: var1,
      var2: var2,
      var3: var3
    }, headers: {
      "X-My-Header" => "something"
    }
```

And here's an error:

```
   Failure/Error:
      put :my_action123, 
        params: { 
          var1: var1,
          var2: var2,
          var3: var3
        }, headers: {
          "X-My-Header" => "something"
        }



     ArgumentError:
       unknown keyword: headers
```

Despite the fact that this what's suggested to use to set headers.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a controller spec? According to https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1655#issuecomment-338903051,

> In request specs you can pass the headers as an argument, in controller specs you need to set the headers directly on the request object.